# waiter for step function state machine execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

My understanding is that boto3's stepfunction client does not provide a way to poll the execution status of a particular execution arn.

Does anyone know how to implement a custom waiter (using the boto3's waiter class) for the execution of a step function in AWS, or know of an existing implementation in python?

Comment: It's just a regular for loop that sleeps 15 seconds and checked the status.

Comment: Found this client API to describe execution
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.describe_execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much cheaper and easier to have a "master" step function run your step function and loop until it's finished.  Or have your step function trigger a lambda when it's completed for an event based solution.